# Finding a list of neo4j nodes which have the most relationships back to another node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph of articles and authors. I want to find the most published author. Then I want to find the list of co-authors for each of the articles. The aim is to work out which co-authors most frequency collaborated with the most productive author.

I'm new to cypher, and I have the most horrible command below that is really inefficient. Is there a better way to do the search?

I also want to them play with the results, so is it best to return the list of coauthors as a collection?

```
MATCH (author:Author)-[:WROTE]->(article:Article) WITH author, COUNT(article) as numberofarticles
ORDER BY numberofarticles DESC LIMIT 1
MATCH (:Author {id:author.id})-[:WROTE]->(article:Article)
MATCH (coauthor:Author)-[:WROTE]->(:Article {id:article.id}) WHERE NOT coauthor:id = author.id
RETURN COUNT(coauthor), article
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can make the query more efficient by keeping the articles from the first `match` in the query.

I think something like this may be what you are looking for.

```
MATCH (author:Author)-[:WROTE]->(article:Article) 
WITH author, COUNT(article) AS number_of_articles, collect(article) AS articles
ORDER BY number_of_articles DESC 
LIMIT 1
UNWIND articles AS article
MATCH (coauthor:Author)-[:WROTE]->(article)
WHERE coauthor <> author
RETURN article, collect(coauthor)
```